# How to change background color of master page ASP .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I change Page Background Color in ASP.NET Client Side and Server Side

I tried

```
.color
{

    PageBody.Attributes.Add("bgcolor", "yellow");
}
```

writing in css file and use as aclass="color"

Comment: Are you trying to do this to change the background at runtime?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to change background color at runtime then you need to define Master Page body in `runat="server"`

that is

```
<body id="MasterBody" runat="server">
</body>
```

If you want to change color in Master Page Load then add below code in Master Page Load Event

```
MasterBody.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: #2e6095");
```

Also if you want to change the body color from an individual page that in the specified master page file, then you first need to find the body control from master page and add the above code there, like

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl MasterBody = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("MasterBody");
MasterBody.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: #2e6095");
```